# Concurrency when working with multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

Consider, I have a `nodes` collection in my MongoDB database:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": 3
  },
  …
]
```

These nodes could form a tree using a `parentId` field.

Now, I want to add an `ancestors` field to a node that would contain an ordered list of all the nodes starting from it's parent and ending with the root node. I.e. for the node with `id = 4` in the example above it would be: `[3, 2, 1]`.

I know, I can retrieve this list using the `$graphLookup` aggregate function. However, how can I make sure that the path of nodes wouldn't change while I'm building and saving this list?

Consider the pseudo code below:

```js
// 1. Get the ancestors list
const ancestors = await collection.aggregate([ { $graphLookup: { … } } ]);

// 2. Updating the node
await collection.updateOne(
  { id: nodeId },
  { $set: { ancestors }}
);
```

What if some of the nodes in the list would be updated in parallel between these two operations? This will lead to incorrect nodes path being stored for the node in question.

How do I make this operation save and ensure the consistency of data in MongoDB?

Comment: I don't think you can do it, because MongoDB doesn't provide "repeatable read" isolation known from most SQL databases. Basically, forget about multi-document consistency.

Comment: Should I make a second aggregate query after updating the node to make sure that the data hasn't changed then?

Comment: @RobertKawecki   Not true for 5 years now.  MongoDB WiredTiger engine supports full adjustable MVCC read isolation levels within a transaction.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/

Comment: @SlavaFominII You are right - recent versions of MongoDB since 4.0 (4.2 for replica sets) offer the "snapshot" isolation level for reads, which apparently do what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has supported multi-document transactions with adjustable read/write isolation for years now.  Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks. But, could you explain how this affects my question?

Comment: You ask "how can I make sure that the path of nodes wouldn't change while I'm building and saving this list?"  You do this by starting a transaction and applying your aggregate and update logic, then committing.   Dirty read/write/collision logic is well documented but beyond scope of your question.  As is starting a transaction and dealing with exceptions, for both the executor *and* other processes updating various nodes in parallel.   This is a transaction/concurrency modeling thing, not a MongoDB thing per se.